# Can we publish an app to AppStore (iOS) using MacOS installed on VMWare?

Tags: ios, app-store, vmware, iphone-developer-program

i have been building an app for iphone using VMware.
So my question is: can I publish my app from MacOS installed on VMware workstation? 
And, What if i sign-in first time and publish the app from real Mac and then work from VMware? will it work?
Is there any other ways that i can publish my app? without real Mac? (it's cost here 2500$, too much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reportedly, you can also rent time by the hour on a remote Mac "in the cloud", and access it via VNC or Remote Desktop.  Make sure to rent one with Xcode and the required SDK already installed for use by User accounts.